# Swift from server to Use

Tags: swift, server

Is there a proper way to request a swift file from a server, and use it functionally in your project in real-time? By possibly adding it to your bundle temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking if it's possible to download a Swift file from a server, and run it on your iOS/iPadOS/watchOS/etc app, the answer is no. Even if you found a way, it would be rejected under rule 2.5.2 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), which states:

> **Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or
>   write data outside the designated container area, nor may they
>   download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes
>   features or functionality of the app, including other apps.**
>   Educational apps designed to teach, develop, or allow students to test
>   executable code may, in limited circumstances, download code provided
>   that such code is not used for other purposes. Such apps must make the
>   source code provided by the Application completely viewable and
>   editable by the user.

Highlight mine.